# Android Studio 3.5, the index time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After I build Android Studio 3.5, the index time becomes Android Studio Layer.

my project was working well but suddenly, Android Studio freezes and I should stop it from task manager. before this happens I installed "Geny motion" & "Virtual Box", but when the error occurred I uninstalled them. but the problem insisted.

Comment: `index time becomes Android Studio Layer` What is this mean by?

Comment: May I know how many ram in your system?

Comment: my leptop is work not push my leptop but Android studio is push not work any option

Comment: my system ram is 8  gb

Comment: i had similar symptoms some time ago, for me that helped: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html

Comment: Who did help similar error

Answer (score 0):

Use of the power saver mode in Android Studio (File -> Power Saver). It reduces the load on the CPU by disabling the background processes.

Also, make sure you don't have any unnecessary applications running in the background on your PC.

**Another option**

- Create a new project and wait for it to get compiled and ready or else open an existing Gradle built project.
- Go to settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle. Tick the offline option.
- Tweak the Gradle to [reduce build time](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/10-tips-to-improve-your-gradle-build-time-1ddeca924759#.spj2thrn9)
- [Disable Unwanted Startup Programs](https://www.howtogeek.com/74523/how-to-disable-startup-programs-in-windows/)

If none of the above steps work, find the path of the file: haxm.exe
Re-install this by double-clicking on it.
While re-installing, manually allot the ram to at least 4 GB since you've got a ram of 8 GB.
It should work properly.